# nHibernate result transformer error

Tags: nhibernate

What is wrong with this?

If I cut and paste the query into a script in SSMS (and properly format it as a query) the code executes in SQL without error.
So the problem is in the reply.

'yourordernumber' is defined as a string in the hbm.xlm mapping and is returned from SQL server as a varchar.

I guess I have two more questions.  Why can't the error exception message include a text that is a simple cut-and-paste to a query script?  And, why can't the error text actually simply tell me what it had an issue with?

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=could not execute query
[ exec OrderLinUpdate
      @Mode=@p0
        , @OrderHdrRecid=@p1
        , @LinNo=@p2
        , @ItemRecid=@p3
        , @QtyRequested=@p4
        , @LoadIDsList=@p5
        , @ItemSelectMethod=@p6
        , @ModifiedBy=@p7 ]
  Name:Mode - Value:Add  Name:OrderHdrRecid - Value:51  Name:LinNo - Value:-1  Name:ItemRecid - Value:97  Name:QtyRequested - Value:1  Name:LoadIDsList - Value:OS 001.0001.1??20300  Name:ItemSelectMethod - Value:SearchLoadID  Name:ModifiedBy - Value:0
[SQL: exec OrderLinUpdate
      @Mode=@p0
        , @OrderHdrRecid=@p1
        , @LinNo=@p2
        , @ItemRecid=@p3
        , @QtyRequested=@p4
        , @LoadIDsList=@p5
        , @ItemSelectMethod=@p6
        , @ModifiedBy=@p7]
  Source=NHibernate
  SqlString=exec OrderLinUpdate
      @Mode=@p0
        , @OrderHdrRecid=@p1
        , @LinNo=@p2
        , @ItemRecid=@p3
        , @QtyRequested=@p4
        , @LoadIDsList=@p5
        , @ItemSelectMethod=@p6
        , @ModifiedBy=@p7
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ListCustomQuery(ICustomQuery customQuery, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.List()
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractQueryImpl.UniqueResult()
       at TKOSMERP.Controllers.ERP.ERPController.OrderLinUpdate(FormCollection pd) in C:\_TKOSVNRepos\TKOSM_ERP\TKOSM_ERP\Controllers\ERP\ERPController_ODELine.cs:line 36
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233080
       Message=yourordernumber
       Source=System.Data
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
            at NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
            at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name)
            at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.Extract(Object[] data, IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.ResultRowProcessor.BuildResultRow(Object[] data, IDataReader resultSet, Boolean hasTransformer, ISessionImplementor session)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.GetResultColumnOrRow(Object[] row, IResultTransformer resultTransformer, IDataReader rs, ISessionImplementor session)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRowFromResultSet(IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, LockMode[] lockModeArray, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, IList hydratedObjects, EntityKey[] keys, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
       InnerException:
```

-- update 
I figured it out.  I had an additional troubleshooting `'select'` statement in the query being executed.  So the proc was actually returning two recordsets; a very common and identifiable situation (also one that is not a problem per-sey) but where in the execution text is this situation identified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had an additional troubleshooting 'select' statement in the query being executed. So the proc was actually returning two recordsets; a very common and identifiable situation (also one that is not a problem per-sey) but where in the execution text is this situation identified?